# Why SSMS tell me its an error although script is working

Tags: sql-server

Script is working, but SSMS say something is wrong. Their are a column with the name score, intelliSense activation and deactivation does not changes.

[image]

Comment: You have asked a number of questions but not marked a single answer. Do your part to make this site useful. Marking answers also gives the answerer credit for the solution (and the work they do for you).

Comment: Try to post details like the table structure if you're asking an SQL question.

Answer (score 1):

Select the Edit menu, select IntelliSense, then select Refresh Local Cache.

Use the CTRL+Shift+R keyboard shortcut.

Disconnect your editor window from the instance of the Database Engine and reconnect.

This behavior happens when you've added a new column or table, SSMS isn't the best at "keeping up".

Comment: @Mail Because SSMS optimizes the editor interface by retrieving the metadata of the database once (mostly). When you create (or modify or delete) objects using tsql, it does not automatically refresh the metadata cache. The editor would be very, very slow if it did this refresh after every statement/script execution.